# C - Creating node with multiple children by function - segmentation fault

Tags: c, tree, segmentation-fault, malloc

I want to create tree with multiple children and create every node with a function. Here is my structure for node:

```
typedef struct node {
   char *string; // Name of the node

   int number_of_children;

   struct node *children[];
} node;
```

And here is my function to create new node (with four children):

```
node *add_node(char *string, node *left, node *middle_left, node *middle_right, node *right) {
   node *p;
   if ((p = malloc(sizeof(node))) == NULL) yyerror("Memory error");

   p->string = strdup(string);

   p->children[p->number_of_children] = left;
   p->children[p->number_of_children + 1] = middle_left;
   p->children[p->number_of_children + 2] = middle_right;
   p->children[p->number_of_children + 3] = right;

   p->number_of_children = 4;

   return p;
}
```

When I run this function value under `p->string` is changed to some garbage. When I wanted to set fixed number of children (in the structure I changed `struct node *children[]` to `struct node *children[4]`) I get segmentation fault. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: `p->number_of_children` isn't initialised to zero as it ought to be. You are working on a fresh node, so you could use just 0, 1, 2 and 3 as indices and set `p->number_of_children` to 4 later. That will work only if you set the dimension of the children array to 4.

Comment: `struct node *children[];` If you think this means "magically make the array big enough for whatever I later decide to put in", then I have some bad news for you.

Comment: `strdup` already copies the string; there's no need to call `strcpy`, although is can't hurt. `strdup` is essentially a combination of `malloc` and `strcpy´.

Comment: I removed the strcpy but it didn't work. And I know, that in the structure there should be fixed number of children (`struct node *children[4]`), but when I change it, I get segmentation fault.

Comment: Why do you allocate memory when you overwrite the handle immediately with the value of `left`, `middle_left`, and so on? Don't allocate, just assign the pointers.

Comment: I removed allocations, but I still get this error

Comment: Ye-e-e-es, because you index with the uninitialised `p->number_of_children` and you still don't allocate 4 elements to `children`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you define your struct, you must know how many children you can have beforehand, because you have to allocate the memory for the last member explicitly:

```
node *p = malloc(sizeof(node) + nchildren * sizeof(node));
```

You could reallocate to accomodate more nodes later, but this isn't a feasible approach here, because the handle to the reallocated memory might change, which will break the tree connectivity.

There are better approaches to have nodes with a varying number of children, for example:

- Settle on a fixed maximum number of children, maybe 4, and make the member array `children` explicitly 4 elements long. Keep a number that tells you how many children are valid.
- Make the list of children a dynamically allocated array that you can reallocate later. This means you have a two-level allocation: First thze node proper, then a list of its children.
- Keep a linked list of child nodes. Come to think of it, you could rearrange the tree so that each node has a `child` for its oldest child node and a `sibling` node fo the next oldest sibling of each node.

I'm not sure what you want to do exactly, but the first approach seems to be the simplest for your concerns.

Your code has several other errors:

- You should only allocate memory when you create a node. Obviously, you already pass in valid node handles to your function. These nodes have already memory allocated to them or they are `NULL`. The following:

  ```
  p = malloc(sizeof(*p));
  p = pref;
  ```

  will allocate memory and immediately lose the only handle to that memory, which is a memory leak. You don't need to allocate here, just say `p = pref`.
- The memory allocated with `malloc` isn't initialised; it contains garbage. Initialise all struct members before you use them. Alternatively, consider using `calloc`, which allocates and zeroes out the memory.
- Combined assignments and checks as in `if ((p = malloc(sizeof(node))) == NULL)` are valid, but complicated to read. In my opinion, they are better separated into assignment and subsequent check. (After all, it just saves you typing `p` twice at  the cost of some extra parantheses.)

An example where you pass in a variable number of chilödren by array might look like this:

```
typedef struct node {
   char *string;    
   size_t number_of_children;    
   struct node *children[4];
} node;

node *add_node(char *string, node *child[], size_t n) 
{
   node *p  = malloc(sizeof(*p));
   size_t i;

   if (p == NULL) yyerror("Memory error");

   p->string = strdup(string);

   for (i = 0; i < n; i++) p->children[i] = child[i];    
   p->number_of_children = n;

   return p;
}
```